# Win 10 Installing usbser.sys over custom driver

Tags: windows-10

I am a USB serial driver developer for CDC devices. Initially we have tested our device driver over all versions of windows it worked fine and well. Now as per customer requirement we had to move towards windows 10, As we know windows 10 is by default shipping usbser.sys(WDF) for CDC devices of class-2 and subclass-2 type even the WDM driver we developed belongs to same type of class.
As per MSDN(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn707976(v=vs.85).aspx) to overcome usbser.sys we have to input hardware ID's in .INF file we did so.

Even after placing VID's & PID's in .INF file it is by default loading usbser.sys.

Rank wise when observed in setupapi.dev log file Our WDM driver is having best rank(0X00FF 0001) and for usbser.sys(0X00FF 2000) even then it is loading usbser.sys as best driver.

My question is, PNP manager in windows 10 is giving high preference to WDF drivers over WDM drivers irrespective of driver ranks assigned as per Hardware ID's and composite ID's match?

Comment: we are facing the above stated problem since we migrated to windows 10 and worked fine on all versions of windows. Usbser.sys in windows 10 overriding custom driver. Anyone who overcome d this problem? please do help in finding the solution

Comment: Same issue here, any solution found?